# How to return data from a private access variable?

Tags: java, return

This is a program that asks the user to enter 1 to store name. Then the program will prompt the user to enter his/her name. After, the program stores the data in an array. Then i have to use a method to do the storage. However, I have a getter and setter methods but i get an error "error: Name has private access in className".

I would like to return the name from my "className" constructors.

I appreciate your assistance. Thanks.

Main Class "ReturnName"

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class ReturnName
    {
  public static void main (String[] args)
    {

className x = new className();



int menu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose an option:" + "\n" + 
                                                        "Enter 1 to store name"));

if(menu == 1){
String[] input1 = new String[1];

for(int i = 0; i < input1.length; i ++){

String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");

input1[i] = str1;


} 
method(input1);

}


}public static void method(String [] input1){ 


String Name = "";



for(int i = 0; i < input1.length; i++){



    Name = input1[i];


}   
className HoldName = new className();
System.out.println(HoldName.Name);

   }


   }
```

className

```
class className{

private int Menu;
private String Name;


public className(){  

   Menu = 0;
   Name = "";

}

public className(String n, int m){

   Menu = m;
   Name = n;


}
public String getName(){

    return Name;
}

public int getMenu(){

    return Menu;
}



public void setName(String n){

    Name = n;
}

public void setMenu(int m){

    Menu = m;
}


     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes because the access modifier of `Name` is private and you can't access it this way, so instead of directly calling `HoldName.Name` use getter method `HoldName.getName()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i enter the name nothing prints on the screen.

Comment: Because you are not setting it anywhere, aftr this className HoldName = new className(); set Name by calling getting method i.e. HoldName.setName(Name);

Comment: Nice! would you mind accepting any of the two answer as correct ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ReturnName` attempts to read the value of the private variable `Name`. Remember that a private variable is just that: **private**, i.e. it can only be read and written from the object where that variable is declared. If other objects want to access that variable, they must go through the getter method.

EDIT: the name is not printed because the method `setName` is never called. The for loop in `method` is also wrong.

Do:

```
 public static void method(String name){ 
  className holdName = new className();
  className.set(name);
  System.out.println(holdName.getName());
 }
```

And call it as:

```
 String str1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");
 method(str1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when i enter the name nothing prints on the screen.